# Issue with sending envelope for signing using API (but website works)

Tags: python, json, rest, docusignapi

I am using the DocuSign sandbox to try to create a program that automatically sends documents for signing to new hires.

Using the request signature tab here: http://iodocs.docusign.com/#?version= and filling it out with the appropriate information works perfectly, however when I attempt to re-implement this myself in Python I am getting a runtime error returned from the docusign server.

Code included below (minus credentials, hah) if anyone has any ideas where I am going wrong.  Thanks!

```
import json
import urllib2
import requests

url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/:<accountid>/envelopes"

headers={
    "X-DocuSign-Authentication":
        "{\"Username\":\"<username>\",\"Password\":\"<password>\",\"IntegratorKey\":\"<integratorkey>\"}"
}

payload={
  "emailSubject": "Test Sign",
  "emailBlurb": "warglbargl",
  "templateId": "B260F219-0F21-43F0-A805-7357FE86F504",
  "templateRoles": [
    {
      "roleName": "Signer",
      "name": "Tester",
      "email": "example@example.com"
    }
  ],
  "status":"sent"
}


response = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers, verify=False)

print response.text
```

**EDIT: here's the error I get**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Runtime Error</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <style>
         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;}
         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
         pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}
         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
         .version {color: gray;}
         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
         @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
          pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }
         }
         @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
          pre { width: 280px; }
         }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="white">

            <span><H1>Server Error in '/restapi' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>

            <h2> <i>Runtime Error</i> </h2></span>

            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

            <b> Description: </b>An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.
            <br><br>

            <b>Details:</b> To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a &lt;customErrors&gt; tag within a &quot;web.config&quot; configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This &lt;customErrors&gt; tag should then have its &quot;mode&quot; attribute set to &quot;Off&quot;.<br><br>

            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                      <code><pre>

&lt;!-- Web.Config Configuration File --&gt;

&lt;configuration&gt;
    &lt;system.web&gt;
        &lt;customErrors mode=&quot;Off&quot;/&gt;
    &lt;/system.web&gt;
&lt;/configuration&gt;</pre></code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>

            <br>

            <b>Notes:</b> The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the &quot;defaultRedirect&quot; attribute of the application&#39;s &lt;customErrors&gt; configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.<br><br>

            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                      <code><pre>

&lt;!-- Web.Config Configuration File --&gt;

&lt;configuration&gt;
    &lt;system.web&gt;
        &lt;customErrors mode=&quot;RemoteOnly&quot; defaultRedirect=&quot;mycustompage.htm&quot;/&gt;
    &lt;/system.web&gt;
&lt;/configuration&gt;</pre></code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>

            <br>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post the runtime error you're getting?

Comment: added above  - its sadly not a super helpful error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **Create Envelope from Templates**

[Python Example from the DocuSign Developer Center](http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/requestSignatureFromTemplate#python)

**Example Code:**

```
# DocuSign API Walkthrough 01 (PYTHON) - Request Signature from Template
import sys, httplib2, json;

# Enter your info:
username = "***";
password = "***";
integratorKey = "***";
templateId = "***";

authenticateStr = "<DocuSignCredentials>" \
                    "<Username>" + username + "</Username>" \
                    "<Password>" + password + "</Password>" \
                    "<IntegratorKey>" + integratorKey + "</IntegratorKey>" \
                    "</DocuSignCredentials>";
#
# STEP 1 - Login
#
url = 'https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information'   
headers = {'X-DocuSign-Authentication': authenticateStr, 'Accept': 'application/json'}
http = httplib2.Http()
response, content = http.request(url, 'GET', headers=headers)

status = response.get('status');
if (status != '200'): 
    print("Error calling webservice, status is: %s" % status); sys.exit();

# get the baseUrl and accountId from the response body
data = json.loads(content);
loginInfo = data.get('loginAccounts');
D = loginInfo[0];
baseUrl = D['baseUrl'];
accountId = D['accountId'];

#--- display results
print ("baseUrl = %s\naccountId = %s" % (baseUrl, accountId));

#
# STEP 2 - Create an Envelope with a Recipient and Send...
#

#construct the body of the request in JSON format  
requestBody = "{\"accountId\": \"" + accountId + "\"," + \
                "\"status\": \"sent\"," + \
                "\"emailSubject\": \"API Call for sending signature request from template\"," + \
                "\"emailBlurb\": \"This comes from Python\"," + \
                "\"templateId\": \"" + templateId + "\"," + \
                "\"templateRoles\": [{" + \
                "\"email\": \"" + username + "\"," + \
                "\"name\": \"Name\"," + \
                "\"roleName\": \"Role\" }] }";

# append "/envelopes" to baseURL and use in the request
url = baseUrl + "/envelopes";
headers = {'X-DocuSign-Authentication': authenticateStr, 'Accept': 'application/json'}
http = httplib2.Http()
response, content = http.request(url, 'POST', headers=headers, body=requestBody);
status = response.get('status');
if (status != '201'): 
    print("Error calling webservice, status is: %s" % status); sys.exit();
data = json.loads(content);
envId = data.get('envelopeId');

#--- display results
print ("Signature request sent!  EnvelopeId is: %s\n" % envId);
```

Also, if you post your response you're getting, we can help debug what's going wrong.

Comment: thanks - I missed this when I went through their site.  I'll give it a whirl and see how it goes :)  Added my error message above as well.

Comment: The sample code that you were kind enough to point me to does the trick!  Thanks :)